# Solving for Original Function from Derivative Clues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, chain-rule

Question: Given the function f(x)=[h(p(x))]^2 and h(5)=1, h'(5)=2, h'(1)=3, p(1)=5, p'(1)=7, evaluate f'(1).

I tried solving what p(x) may be and figured the most trivial answer is p(x)=7x-2 (it meets the condition that **p(1)=5**=7(1)-2 and **p'(1)=7**=7(1)).

Next step is finding h(p(x)). I thought that I'd apply the chain rule here and figure out an equation to satisfy h'(5)=2 and h'(1)=3, but I can't figure it out.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the derivative:
$$f'(x) = 2h(p(x))h'(p(x))p'(x)$$
Substitute $1$ in for $x$:
$$f'(1) = 28$$

Comment: but what is h(p(x))?

Comment: I see, I'll attempt to answer it right now

Comment: Why do you need h(p(x))? The question doesn't ask for it. h(p(x)) is likely not well defined.